# Communication problem between my Servlet, Beans and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have a difficulty to make calculation on my beans and show the result on my JSP file
When I execute my code, I have a exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException with this line, the line of problem: `<c:if test="${ !empty tax.AmountWithTax }"><c:out value="${ tax.AmountWithTax }" /></c:if>`

Error message:The AmountWithTax's properties arenot found

Thanks in advance for your help

JSP FORM SOURCE CODE SendStep1.jsp:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="../SendStep1/" name="amount-calculation-form" method="post">
<table   class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td width="170"><strong>Amount Without Tax</strong></td>
    <td width="384">    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="ex: 25000" value="" type="number"  id="amount"   maxlength="6" required>
</div></td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="182"><label>
      <button type="reset" class="">Cancel</button>
    </label></td>
    <td width="384">&nbsp;<label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Make Calculation>></button>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

---

Servlet:SendStep1:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Tax tax = new Tax();
    tax.TaxCalculation(request);
    request.setAttribute("tax", tax);
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "../SendStep1.jsp" ).forward(request, response);
}
```

---

Beans: Tax.class

```
public class Tax {

    private int AmountWithTax;
    public void TaxCalculation(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amount"));

        if( amount <= 2000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 30;
        }else if(amount <= 2500){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 60;
        }else if(amount <= 5000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 75;
        }else if(amount <= 15000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 150;
        }else if(amount <= 25000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 450;
        }else if(amount <= 50000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 750;
        }else if(amount <= 100000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 1500;
        }else if(amount <= 250000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 3000;
        }else if(amount <= 500000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 5000;
        }else if(amount <= 600000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 6000;
        }else if(amount <= 700000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 7000;
        }else if(amount <= 800000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 8000;
        }else if(amount <= 900000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 9000;
        }else if(amount <= 1000000){
            AmountWithTax = amount + 10000;
        }else {
            AmountWithTax = amount + 50000;
        }
    }


    public int getAmountWithTax() {
        return AmountWithTax;
    }

    public void setAmountWithTax(int amountWithTax) {
        AmountWithTax = amountWithTax;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow java naming convention. Try to replace instance variable **AmountWithTax** to **amountWithTax** everywhere in class Tax and JSP accordinly. The reflection works here and doesn't find appropriate get method for field *AmountWithTax*.